# How can I show / hide a div using the properties from a CSS file using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, display

I'm looking to show a div that's initial display value is set to "none" in the HTML file. I don't want to use $(object).style.display = "initial" because it doesn't format the page right. I'm sure there is a way to do this. Can anybody help?

JavaScript:

```
function showPrecip() {
$("slider").style.display = "none";
$("graph").style.display = "initial";}
```

CSS:

```
#graph td div {
background-color: #e7f1fd;
border-top: 2px solid #1878f0;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: center;
width: 50px;}

#graph td, #temps {
height: 100px;
vertical-align: bottom;}
```

HTML:

```
    <table id="graph">
    </table>
    <div id="temps">
        <input id="slider" type="range" min="0" max="24" step="3" />
    </div>
```

Comment: if you use visibility='hidden' => visibility='visible' then their wont be any change to the layout required - is that what you mean?

Comment: If you're using jQuery (which, I can only assume you are given the `$`), then, IMO, it would be better to use `$('.slider').css('display', 'block')`

Comment: Are `slider` and `graph` custom elements ? Can you include `html` at Question ?

Answer (score 0):

Default Behaviour for div is Block.

Just change the javascript to the below should be alright.
As i use this method for this part.
$("graph").style.display = "";

Answer (score 0):

Make a CSS class

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

Toggle it with JS as needed

```
function showPrecip() {
  $("slider").addClass("hidden");
  $("graph").removeClass("hidden");
}
```